# Can't add new lines in JavaScript alert Box?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm generating a string in PHP and then eventually passing this string into a JavaScript alert box, my problem is I actually can't add line breaks in my alert box.

My code looks as follows

```
$str = "This is a string\n";
$alert = $str."This is the second line"; 

    if(!empty($alert)){
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert('<?=$alert?>');
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> Undeterminnated string literal

If I remove the `\n` from the string it works 100% but without line breaks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This happens because PHP interprets the \n before JavaScript has the chance to, resulting in a *real* line break inside the Javascript code.
Try

```
\\n
```

Comment: This makes sense, I tried this and this worked for me, thx Pekka

Comment: Actually this isn't generally enough, since the string may contain quotes and other characters which make code invalid. You should escape the string. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines for how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change `$str` to

```
$str = "This is a string\\n";
```

so that the `\n` gets passed to the JavaScript.