# Javascript slash is missing when called in argument

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008

I am passing a path as an argument in a Javascript.
For example I am passing a path as `c:\my documents\user\aa.jpg` when registering Javascript in client side.

When calling this in a function say, `function js(d)` then the slash goes missing, hence the value of 'd' becomes `c:mydocumentsuseraa.jpg`

What to do?

Comment: Sounds like they need to escaped. Please show the code

Comment: duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748472/cant-add-new-lines-in-javascript-alert-box

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't add new lines in JavaScript alert Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748472/cant-add-new-lines-in-javascript-alert-box)

Answer (score 1):

Have you escaped your backslashes ?

```
alert( 'c:\\my documents\\user\\aa.jpg' );
```

Answer (score 1):

pass it like this:

```
c:\\my documents\\user\\aa.jpg
```

you need to escape the slash char. thanks

> You should always pass the slash char
>   which has special meaning for example,
>   you can use it to specify new lines
>   like \n, tabs \t, etc. So you should
>   escape it with another slash char to
>   make it come single slash char.

Answer (score 0):

You said `when registering javascript in client side`.

I assume you are doing this in the code behind as you have tagged asp.net. 
So I think you would need to use **@** before the string while registering the scipt.

Like `@"c:\abc\xyz.jpg"`

OR you can go by the method Sarfraz mentiond. i.e. pass the string as `"c:\\abc\\xyz.jpg"`

I hope this helps.